# If a paper is having any Ayat or Hadith written on it then in order to save that page from throwing, Can we burn it?

Tags: halal-haram

If a paper is having any Ayat or Hadith written on it then in order to save that page from throwing, Can we burn it? If no, then what is the proper way, so that we dont get any sin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the islamic teaching says that, if a paper is having any Quranic verse(words) or hadith which is not more able to read clearly(and can't be kept safe any more) can be wasted by the following ways: by burying that specific piece of paper into soil, by throwing it in the flowing water(like rivers or sea) or by burning it (if it is the only option remaining).

**By burying**
First of all, wrap that paper into any sheet or cloth which can save it from soil, then dig a deep hole where no disrespecting manners can occur(like, walking of people on that specifis place), and that place should be pure best method is to bury it in graveyard.

*The great Hanafi Imam, Imam Ibn Abidin (may Allah have mercy on him) states:*

> “If a copy of the Mushaf (qur’an) becomes old and it is difficult to
>   read from it, it should not be burnt in fire. This is what Imam
>   Muhammad (m: student of Imam Abu Hanifa) pointed out and this is what
>   we take. It will not be disliked to bury it. It should be wrapped in a
>   pure cloth, and a Lahd grave (m: grave that has a incision in the side
>   wall, customary in hot climate countries where the earth is solid)
>   should be dug, because if a Shiq grave (m: grave with a straight
>   opening, common in cold climate countries due to the earth being soft)
>   is dug and the copy of the Qur’an is buried, it will entail the soil
>   falling on top of the Qur’an which is a form of disrespect, unless a
>   slab is placed as a roof…” (Radd al-Muhtar, 5/271)

**By throwing in the river or sea**
The other method is to throw it in the flowing water of rivers or sea. As the flowing water is said to be the pure water, and water can also remove or wipe the words on that pages. That papers should be thrown after tying with a heavy stone (as papers are light weight and they will float on water surface).

**By burning**
Burning the paper will be cosidered only when the above two options couldn't be applied. Burning process should be on a pure and clean place very carefully and its ash should be buried or thrown into water too.

[Link for the description](https://www.thoughtco.com/disposal-of-quran-2004546)

Answer (score 0):

I think so we can't burn because in past in history of Islam no one burnt and those who burnt Allah punish him badly at the spot if we found any piece of Paper I'm which ayat is written then save the page is best option.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to support your claims?

Comment: Yes according to my knowledge there is no hadith to burnt or I read about people some sahaba some or prophet or saints they all gave repect Or save these pages. And I also read about the story of women in which she Burt QuranPak and Allah punish her at the spot. There are hadith or sunah to save PR gave respect but according to my knowledge no permission to burnt

Comment: that is simply because the first time this happened by order was during the caliphate of 'Othman ibn' Affan